# JQuery - div visibility via checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, toggle, visibility

I have a series of matching checkboxes and divs on my page. Each checkbox needs to be able to show/hide the corresponding div when it is checked/unchecked. Each div starts out hidden on page load. I've read through many threads on similar issues here, but I can't get any of the examples to work for my requirements.

I've set up an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shimmoril/wzMM4/11/. I thought that having style="display: none;" on the div might be messing w/ the JQuery, but when I removed it from the first div the toggle still didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for starters, this fiddle isn't using jQuery & it's doing `$(document).ready(...` and the JS is set to run `onLoad`, so the event already fired and won't start running your code

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" />
```

Yet your JQuery is looking for a class:

```
 $('.checkbox1').change(function() {
    $('#div1').toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

It should be: $('#checkbox1')

Comment: Yep, I'm a JQuery newb. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I saw two things wrong with your jsfiddle.  One, you had it set to MooTools and you're trying to test jQuery.  Second, you need to set the selector for checkbox1 as an ID, not a class (i.e. # instead of .)

Change your fiddle to jQuery and then use this script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
        $('#div1').toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I'm pretty new to JSFiddle and JQuery, as you might have guessed.

Comment: No worries, gotta start somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

If all of the divs are to start hidden and all of the checkboxes are to start unchecked then you can just call toggle() in the change event: http://jsfiddle.net/wzMM4/12/

If that might not be the case you should add some code first to synchronize the div visibility in page load: http://jsfiddle.net/wzMM4/26/

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle doesn't run as saved because it's using MooTools, and - a key point, I think - you are referencing the *class* of the checkbox instead of its id. Updating it to use jquery and changing your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
        $('#div1').toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});​
```

Makes it work. If you're sure of the layout, you can use something akin to the following to take care of ALL of the checkboxes, in a generic way - this will, after checking any checkbox, toggle the second following element (your div):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $(this).next().next().toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sheldon, I'll have to play with this a bit more, but it looks like a good starting point.